# Javafx style class path nullpointer

Tags: java, javafx, resources, styles

I'm trying to load style.css from relative path, but I'm getting nullpoiter exception. I've searched in many post and still couldn't get proper solution. Here is one of my attempts:

```
lineChart.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("../resources/styles/styles.css").toExternalForm());
```

And here is my project structure:

[image]

Comment: You've already got a working answer, but for future reference: `getResource` does not support the use of `..` in the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
`lineChart.getStylesheets().addAll(getClass().getResource("/styles/styles.css").toExternalForm());`

`getResource()` looks for the resources folder, so there's no need to add a `../resources` in your file path.